# Wrapping markup in conditional elements in Slightly?

Tags: aem, sightly

If I needed to wrap every 5th item in a div, how can this be done in Slighlty?  I thought this would work, but the closing tag for the div is never rendered.  I can use a test in the opening div, but I can't have a test in the closing div.

```
<ul>
 <sly data-sly-test="${menuItemList.index == 0}"><div class="row-of-five"></sly>
  <li data-i="${menuItemList.index}">
   <a>${menuItem.linkText @ context = 'html'}</a>
  </li>
 <sly data-sly-test="${menuItemList.index == 5}"></div></sly>
</ul>
```

[image: Example of markup rendered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this cannot be done in HTL directly because HTL always presumes valid nesting, which a single opening or closing `<div>`, as you have it in your `sly data-sly-test` elements, isn’t.

But you could create lists of five in your model and then render those with  nested `data-sly-repeat`/`data-sly-list` instructions.

Though I hope this is pseudocode since your example would be invalid markup as `<ul>` tags are only allowed to have `<li>` children, not `<div>`s.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all your elements with div and use `data-sly-unwrap` to remove wrapping for all elements except every 5th element:

```
<div data-sly-unwrap="${...}">...</div>
```

If the expression inside `${}` is evaluated to `true`, only inner content of  `div` element will be rendered, but not `div` itself.